# How to consider the nesting level when looping through a nested list?

Tags: python

My input is a nested list :

```
data = ['aaa', ['eee', ['ccc', 'zzz', ['fff']], 'yyy']]
```

And I need to rearange it in a very specific way. Let me put some comments to explain the logic :

```
expected_output = [
    ['aaa', 'eee'], # bcz eee is the first non-list item inside the next list that follows aaa
    ['aaa', 'yyy'], # bcz yyy is the second non-list item inside the next list that follows aaa
    ['eee', 'ccc'], # bcz ccc is the first non-list item inside the next list that follows eee
    ['eee', 'zzz'], # bcz zzz is the second non-list item inside the next list that follows eee
    ['zzz', 'fff'], # bcz fff is the first non-list item inside the next list that follows zzz
]
```

I tried some sort of recursive function but it's not good at all :

```
def my_func(item):
    output = []
    for i in item:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            yield i
        else:
            output.append([i, my_func(i)])
```

Here is the wrong output I'm getting :

```
print(list(my_func(data)))

[['eee', ['ccc', 'zzz', ['fff']], 'yyy']]
```

The first item of the input list is always a non-list. Also the order of the items in each output pair matters, but  not the order in which the pairs are printed/returned relative to each other.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not good at all"?

Comment: Those are lists, not tuples.

Comment: Scott, I updated the post to make it more precise. Tim, thanks but even with list it ain't good.

Comment: What should be produced for `['x', ['a', ['b'], 'c', ['d'], 'e'], 'y']` and why?

Comment: `['ccc', 'fff']` shouldn't be in the output?

Comment: Could you have an input as `['aaa', [ ['eee', 'ccc'], ['zzz', 'fff'], 'yyy']]` ?

Comment: That's a good question.  Based on his rule, I assume that every list must begin with a string.

Comment: IgnatiusReilly, no because 'ccc' isn't immediately followed by a list.

Comment: Scotter and RomanPerekhrest, no that's not a potential scenario.

Comment: Tim, yes every list starts with a non-list object.

Comment: @VERBOSE, Is the result `[['aaa', 'eee'], ['eee', 'ccc'], ['eee', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'fff'], ['aaa', 'yyy']]` acceptable? Or it should be in strict order?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, thank you. I missed that point. The outer order is not important. However, the order of the inner list is important. So, yes, your output is acceptable.

Comment: @VERBOSE Comments are not a place to clarify problem description, that why the edit option exists. The fact that every list starts with a string is important information that we shouldn't have to dig out of a dozen comments. In the future, please make an attempt to put all pertinent information in the question to avoid wasting time for those volunteering on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With specific recursive function basing on capturing a *parent* key from the outer list and postponed processing of inner lists:

(Considering the condition that *"every list starts with a non-list object"*)

```
def zip_nested_pairs(lst, p_key=None):
    if not p_key:   
        p_key = lst[0]  # initialize the 1st parent key
        lst = lst[1:]   # slice the rest
    inner_list, next_key = None, None
    for v in lst:
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            yield [p_key, v]    # yield value with its jointed parent key
            if not inner_list:
                next_key = v    # capture the key prior to the inner list
        else:
            inner_list = v
    if inner_list:
        yield from zip_nested_pairs(inner_list, next_key or p_key)

print(list(zip_nested_pairs(data)))
```

---

```
[['aaa', 'eee'], ['aaa', 'yyy'], ['eee', 'ccc'], ['eee', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'fff']]
```

---

**Update**: 
If initializing the 1st *parent* key with direct indexing is not quite suitable, you can switch to the following version:

```
def zip_nested_pairs(lst, p_key=None):
    inner_list, next_key = None, None
    for v in lst:
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            if not p_key:
                p_key = v  # initialize the 1st parent key
                continue
            yield [p_key, v]    # yield value wit its jointed parent key
            if not inner_list:
                next_key = v    # capture the key prior to the inner list
        else:
            inner_list = v
    if inner_list:
        yield from zip_nested_pairs(inner_list, next_key or p_key)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a very odd way to parse, but this will do it.

Here's the rule.  For every element in the current list, if it is a string, remember it as the next "key".  If it is a list, scan the list and yield the [key,value] pairs for every element of that sublist that is a string, AND recursively call to do the same processing again.

```
data = ['aaa', ['eee', ['ccc', 'zzz', ['fff']], 'yyy']]

def scan(key,lst):
    for v in lst:
        if isinstance(v,str):
            yield [key,v]

def convert( lst ):
    for v in lst:
        if isinstance(v,str):
            key = v
        else:
            yield from scan(key,v)
            yield from convert(v)

for pair in convert(data):
    print(pair)
```

Output:

```
['aaa', 'eee']
['aaa', 'yyy']
['eee', 'ccc']
['eee', 'zzz']
['zzz', 'fff']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without scanning the whole list for each item, and that works even if the first item is not a string. The idea is to attach each string in a list with the last string from a previous list. This can be done using a stack.

```
def parse(data: list[str | list[str]]) -> list[list[str]]:
    def loop(data: list[str | list[str]], i: int, level: int, prev: list[tuple[str, int]]) -> None:
        if i >= len(data):
            return
        # Process i-th item in this level.
        if isinstance(data[i], str):
            # Find the last string from the previous level.
            j = next((i for i in range(len(prev) - 1, -1, -1) if prev[i][1] < level), -1)
            if j >= 0:
                ans.append([prev[j][0], data[i]])
            # First string in this level.
            if not prev or prev[-1][1] < level:
                prev.append((data[i], level))
            # Overwrite previous string in this level.
            else:
                prev[-1] = (data[i], level)
        else:
            # Recur with the last string from the previous level.
            loop(data[i], 0, level + 1, prev[-1:])

        # Process the next item in this level.
        loop(data, i + 1, level, prev)

    ans: list[list[str]] = []
    loop(data, 0, 0, [])
    return ans
```

> [['aaa', 'eee'], ['eee', 'ccc'], ['eee', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'fff'], ['aaa', 'yyy']]

Note that the stack never grows more than 2 items, so, the space usage is constant.
The time complexity is O(n), where n is the number of integers.

Answer (score 0):

In case if the output order can be less strict (to *depth* level reflection) here's another recursive approach based on relation between *depth* level and an auxiliary list of *parent* keys:

```
def zip_nested_pairs(lst, p_keys=None, depth=0):
    next_key = None
    for v in lst:
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            if not p_keys:
                p_keys = [v]  # initialize parent keys list
                continue
            yield [p_keys[depth - 1], v]  # number of parent keys is (depth + 1)
            next_key = v
        else:
            if next_key: p_keys.append(next_key)  # capture the key prior to the inner list
            yield from zip_nested_pairs(v, p_keys, depth + 1)

print(list(zip_nested_pairs(data)))
```

---

```
[['aaa', 'eee'], ['eee', 'ccc'], ['eee', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'fff'], ['aaa', 'yyy']]
```